# Redirect URL as well as Change Query String Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I have two conditions:

> http://localhost/restexample/api/con/2/

rewrites to

> http://localhost/restexample/RestController.php?phone=single&id=2

and

> http://localhost/restexample/api?number=12345

redirects/rewrites to

> http://localhost/restexample/RestController.php?phone=all&no=12345

I am getting proper response in 1st case but not in second case.

My .htaccess file is:

```
# Turn rewrite engine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule api/con/([0-9]+)/$   "RestController.php?phone=single&id=$1" [nc,qsa]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} number=(\d+)$     
RewriteRule "^api"  "RestController.php?phone=all&no=%1" [nc,qsa,R=301]
```

Somebody please help.

Output of second file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# map neat URL to internal URL
RewriteRule ^api/con/([0-9]+)/?$ RestController.php?phone=single&id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)number=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^api/?$ RestController.php?phone=all&no=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: 403 error. It is located at xampp/htdocs/restexample. See image. Address in addressbar.

Comment: URL shown in image is `http://localhost/restexample/12345` but this rule is for `http://localhost/restexample/api?number=1234‌​5`

Comment: sorry that is the result of calling localhost/restexample/api?number=12345. It should actually go to localhost/restexample/RestController.php but error 403 is coming with above url in address bar

Comment: I don't get it. Your first rule like mine is working perfectly well. Then how is there a cache problem. Since I am an android developer can you tell me a shortcut to clear browser cache in chrome. Yes I checked, localhost/restexample/RestController.php?phone=all&no=12345 is working perfectly well.

Comment: The fact that your browser is redirecting to `http://localhost/restexample/12345` means there is some old caching problem. You should be able to clear browser cache in any browser and for testing rewrite rules you should use a desktop browsers.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow. Currently, I am at home and code is on office pc. Thanks for you guidance :)

Comment: Thanks Man!! It is working today.So maybe browser cache must have been the problem as you said. Sorry for late reply. It would be great of you to explain where was I doing mistake!! Again Thanks a LOT!! :)